# Google Sheets query doesn't work with join

Tags: google-sheets

How to deal with it?

My query is:

`=join("-", query('Asin (Parent и Child)'!A3:F3649; "select F where E = '"&B5&"'"))`

It responds:

"Formula parse error."

I tried join and textjoin and arrayformula and non of this worked.

Comment: Just try with *semicolon convention* maybe: `=join("-"; query('Asin (Parent и Child)'!A3:F3649; "select F where E = '"&B5&"'"))`

Comment: @rockinfreakshow It works! Why??? In the docs just comma is used: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en

Comment: [this should help](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/)

Answer (score 0):

@rockinfreakshow gave me working answer in the comments. Here it is

> Just try with semicolon convention maybe: =join("-"; query('Asin
> (Parent и Child)'!A3:F3649; "select F where E = '"&B5&"'"))

```
=join("-"; query('Asin (Parent и Child)'!A3:F3649; "select F where E = '"&B5&"'"))
```

<-- it works!

Or he (or she) may write the post itself and I delete this. I don't know how is better guys) New here

P.S. Strangely, Google itself gives incorrect information within its docs:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en

where comma is used.

Comment: Depending on your *sheet locale* setting; country-specific google support documentation showcasing the *semicolon convention* can be found by say changing the url part `hl=en` to [hl=es](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=es) OR [hl=nl](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=nl)